# Near Protocol | RPC Contract deployment | Deserialization error

Tags: deserialization, smartcontracts, nearprotocol, near, assemblyscript

I am developing smart contracts in AssemblyScript, deploying contracts via RPC (Remote Procedural Calls), that is dynamically, while coding as and when required. Below is the code that carries out this task.

```
log(): void {
logging.log(this.owner);

const access_key = base58.decode(Context.senderPublicKey);
logging.log(access_key);

const CODE = base58.decode("build/release/nft.wasm");

ContractPromiseBatch
  .create("d4." + this.owner)
  .create_account()
  .transfer(ONE_NEAR)
  .add_full_access_key(access_key)
  .deploy_contract(CODE);
}
```

After the code the new account has been created and the contract code deployed, I get a deserialization error even while carrying out the init calls for initialising the contract.

The error log is :

```
Failure:
{
  "ActionError": {
    "index": 0,
    "kind": {
      "FunctionCallError": {
        "CompilationError": {
          "PrepareError": "Deserialization"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The link to the transaction : https://explorer.testnet.near.org/transactions/2HjNsq6ytnN3hT9odoijaYxBsByhQQcwSUTZNwGgzuyg

Heres the init method of the contract I am trying to initialize

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears the correct way to include your wasm code while deploying the contract is

```
const CODE = includeBytes("../../../build/release/nft.wasm");
```

and while deploying, parse CODE into base58 array

```
let promise = ContractPromiseBatch
  .create("kust" + "." + this.owner)
  .create_account()
  .transfer(ONE_NEAR)
  .add_full_access_key(access_key)
  .deploy_contract(Uint8Array.wrap(changetype<ArrayBuffer>(CODE)));
```

Comment: A proper example of this can be found here 
https://github.com/Learn-NEAR/NCD.L1.sample--meme-museum/blob/8c5d025d363f89fdcc7335d58d61a8e3307cd95a/src/museum/assembly/index.ts#L85